# is there any way i can download full text in tweeter using python

Tags: python-3.x, file, download, full-text-search, tweepy

I am trying to download tweets based on keywords, and this is the piece of code I am using for that, but the problem is I am unable to download the entire tweet. It is showing only the first 140 characters. How to download the full tweet?

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
####input your credentials here
consumer_key =''
consumer_secret =''
access_token =''
access_token_secret=''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
#####United Airlines
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open(r'C:\Users\iiit\Desktop\tweets.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#hashtag",count=1000,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2020-04-14").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official tweepy documentation:

tweepy.API methods that return status objects (tweets) accept a parameter, which can either be compatibility or extended mode. The default parameter is compatibility mode. Compatibility mode truncates tweets to 140 characters. That's what your program is currently doing.

You should use extended mode if you want the entire text. Pass the kwag `tweet_mode="extended"` to declare the mode you intend to use. Then instead of `tweet.text` use `tweet.full_text`

Your new code should look like this;

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
    q="#hashtag", count=5, lang="en",
    since="2020-05-07", tweet_mode="extended").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
```

I haven't tested, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is a policy that Compatibility mode truncates tweets to 140 characters. But this Status event handler possible to use for a StreamListener prints the full text of the Tweet, or if it’s a Retweet, the full text of the Retweeted Tweet as their documentation.

```
  def on_status(self, status):
        if hasattr(status, "retweeted_status"):  # Check if Retweet
            try:
                print(status.retweeted_status.extended_tweet["full_text"])
            except AttributeError:
                print(status.retweeted_status.text)
        else:
            try:
                print(status.extended_tweet["full_text"])
            except AttributeError:
                print(status.text)
```

This may help you.[here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html?highlight=download%20full%20text)

Comment: hi there Hashan - mille gracie - looks impressive.  And yes:  i think that this helps here very good.

Comment: Great.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is a policy that Compatibility mode truncates tweets to 140 characters. Tthe full text of the Retweeted Tweet as their documentation.

```
def on_status(self, status):
    if hasattr(status, "retweeted_status"):  # Check if Retweet
        try:
            print(status.retweeted_status.extended_tweet["full_text"])
        except AttributeError:
            print(status.retweeted_status.text)
    else:
        try:
            print(status.extended_tweet["full_text"])
        except AttributeError:
            print(status.text)
```

This may help you.[here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html?highlight=download%20full%20text)